# Redo function as SQL only call

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement that I am coding in C# but I think I can do in SQL but I can't figure it out without using a bunch of cursers.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
Row_Type Period_1  Period_2  Period_3 ... Period_18
FFT      600.0     200.0     300.0        0.0
END      500.0     150.0     200.0        0.0
WK#        2.0       0.5       1.0        0.0
```

The WK# is the number of Period's EFT values after the current Period that can go into the current END value.  So for `Period_1` the `END` is 500 which covers `Period_2 FFT` (200.0) and `Period_3 FFT` (300.0) so the `WK#` is 2.0.   `Period_2 END` is 150.0 which only covers 50% of `Period_3 FFT` so its `WK#` is 0.5.  This goes on for all 18 Periods.

Any ideas how to go about this in SQL.  I am using MS SQL server 2005.

The FFT is the expected amount of widgets needed for the Period, the END is the amount of widgets on hand for the Period, the WK# is the number of Periods going forward that the supply of widgets on hand (the END) can satisfy.  So in the example data for Period_1 we are predicting that we will have enough supply (END) to cover the expected demand (FFT) for the next two Periods (WK# = 2.0).  The Period is usually a week thus why its called WK#.

**Sorry I now realize this was not clear but I am trying to Calculate the WK#, I have the FFT and END values**.

Comment: Without more details this a crap shoot. Please provide a more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry, really struggling to understand what your setup is here.  You have a table that is row_type, period1,period_2,etc?

Comment: Maybe if you unpivot your data, the calculation would be easier because you would be working with rows and not columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like ..

```
declare @t table (Row_Type varchar(10), Period_1 decimal(8,2), Period_2 decimal(8,2), Period_3 decimal(8,2), Period_4 decimal(8,2))
insert into @t (Row_Type, Period_1, Period_2, Period_3, Period_4)
select 'FFT', 600.0, 200.0, 300.0, 0.0
union all
select 'WK#', 2.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0
    if object_id('tempdb..#temptable') is not null
drop table #temptable

select Row_Number() over (order by Row_Type) as rownum, Row_Type, Period, PerValue
    into #temptable
from
    ( select Row_Type, Period_1, Period_2, Period_3, Period_4
    from @t
    where row_Type = 'FFT'
    ) as p
    unpivot
    (PerValue for Period in (Period_1, Period_2, Period_3, Period_4)) as unpvt;

insert into @t (Row_Type, Period_1, Period_2, Period_3, Period_4)
    select 
        'END' as Row_Type
        , (select sum(PerValue) * case when Period_1 < 1 then Period_1 else 1 end from #temptable where rownum >= 2 and rownum <= round(1 + Period_1,0,0) ) as Period_1
        , (select sum(PerValue) * case when Period_2 < 1 then Period_2 else 1 end  from #temptable where rownum >= 3 and rownum <= round(2+ Period_1,0,0) ) as Period_2
        , (select sum(PerValue) * case when Period_3 < 1 then Period_3 else 1 end  from #temptable where rownum >= 4 and rownum <= round(3+ Period_1,0,0) ) as Period_3
        , 0.0 as Period_4
    from @t
    where Row_Type = 'WK#'

select *
from @t
```

Modified example below. There may be better solutions (using functions or other logic)

```
    declare @t table (Row_Type varchar(10), Period_1 decimal(8,2), Period_2 decimal(8,2), Period_3 decimal(8,2), Period_4 decimal(8,2))

insert into @t (Row_Type, Period_1, Period_2, Period_3, Period_4)
select 'FFT', 600.0, 200.0, 300.0, 0.0
union all
select 'END', 500.0, 150.0, 200.0, 0.0

insert into @t (Row_Type, Period_1, Period_2, Period_3, Period_4)
select 
    case
        when RTEND.Period_1 <= RTFFT.Period_2 then RTEND.Period_1 / RTFFT.Period_2
        when RTEND.Period_1 <= (RTFFT.Period_2 + RTFFT.Period_3) then 2.0
        when RTEND.Period_1 <= (RTFFT.Period_2 + RTFFT.Period_3 + RTFFT.Period_4) then 3.0
        end as Period_1
    ,   case
        when RTEND.Period_2 <= RTFFT.Period_3 then RTEND.Period_2 / RTFFT.Period_3
        when RTEND.Period_2 <= (RTFFT.Period_3 + RTFFT.Period_4) then 2.0
        end as Period_2
    , case
        when RTEND.Period_3 <= RTFFT.Period_4 then RTEND.Period_3 / RTFFT.Period_4 
        else 1.0
        end as Period_3
    , 0.0 AS Period_4
from
(
    select 1 as ID, *
    from @t
    where Row_Type = 'FFT'
) RTFFT
inner join
(
    select 1 as ID, *
    from @t
    where Row_Type = 'END'
) RTEND
on RTFFT.ID = RTEND.ID

select *
from @t
```

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear but I am trying to calc the WK# based on a given END and FFT.  I have been playing around with it and have come up with something similar to what you have which at least validates my current approach so far.

Comment: T_M this seems to work, I will play with it tomorrow.  As it is, it is more readable then what I did but I will have to add a ton more CASE and WHEN statements to cover all 17 periods I have.

Comment: It may not be the most elegant of code and yes you will need a whole load of case when statements for 17 periods.

Comment: Not sure how to pick the better answer.  The data set is so small speed is not an issue and neither is very elegant so I marked this one since it is easier to read and maintain.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This spaghetti is what I came up with today.  It works but it is not pretty.  I started with the suggestion that Kevin Cook offered (I do not hold him accountable for the outcome)

```
if object_id('tempdb..#LookupGFT') is not null
drop table #LookupGFT

if object_id('tempdb..#TempCalc') is not null
drop table #TempCalc


SELECT *
INTO #LookupGFT
FROM(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Period) RowNo, Period, GFT 
FROM
(SELECT period01, period02, period03, period04, period05, period06, period07, period08, period09, period10, period11, period12, period13, period14, 
                      period15, period16, period17
FROM         CombineSnapshot_detail
WHERE row_type = 'GFT') p
UNPIVOT
(GFT FOR Period IN (period01, period02, period03, period04, period05, period06, period07, period08, period09, period10, period11, period12, period13, period14, 
                      period15, period16, period17)) as unpvt) adb


SELECT style_pkey, Period, [END], [WK#], IsNull(WholePeriods,0) as WholePeriods, IsNull(wholePeriodsTotal,0) as wholePeriodsTotal, IsNull(RemainderGFT,0) as RemainderGFT
INTO #TempCalc
FROM
(SELECT RowNo, style_pkey, Period, [END], [WK#], 
CASE WHEN [END] < 1 THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT MAX(rowNo) FROM 
    (SELECT RowNo, Period, GFT, isNull((SELECT SUM(GFT) FROM #LookupGFT WHERE (RowNo - mainData.RowNo <= lup2.RowNo) and (RowNo > mainData.RowNo)),0) RUNNING_TOTAL
    FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Period) RowNo, Period, GFT
        FROM(
            SELECT Period, GFT
            FROM #LookupGFT LGFT
            WHERE RowNo > mainData.RowNo
            ) Lup1
        ) lup2
    ) abc WHERE abc.RUNNING_TOTAL < mainData.[END]) END as wholePeriods,
CASE WHEN [END] < 1 THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT MAX(RUNNING_TOTAL) FROM 
    (SELECT RowNo, Period, GFT, isNull((SELECT SUM(GFT) FROM #LookupGFT WHERE (RowNo - mainData.RowNo <= lup2.RowNo) and (RowNo > mainData.RowNo)),0) RUNNING_TOTAL
    FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Period) RowNo, Period, GFT
        FROM(
            SELECT Period, GFT
            FROM #LookupGFT LGFT
            WHERE RowNo > mainData.RowNo
            ) Lup1
        ) lup2
    ) abc WHERE abc.RUNNING_TOTAL < mainData.[END]) END as wholePeriodsTotal,

CASE WHEN [END] < 1 THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT TOP (1) GFT FROM 
    (SELECT RowNo, Period, GFT, isNull((SELECT SUM(GFT) FROM #LookupGFT WHERE (RowNo - mainData.RowNo <= lup2.RowNo) and (RowNo > mainData.RowNo)),0) RUNNING_TOTAL
    FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Period) RowNo, Period, GFT
        FROM(
            SELECT Period, GFT
            FROM #LookupGFT LGFT
            WHERE RowNo > mainData.RowNo
            ) Lup1
        ) lup2
    ) abc WHERE abc.RUNNING_TOTAL > mainData.[END] ORDER BY RowNo) END as RemainderGFT

FROM(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Period) RowNo, style_pkey, Period, [END], CAST(0 as FLOAT) as [WK#]
FROM
(SELECT style_pkey, period01, period02, period03, period04, period05, period06, period07, period08, period09, period10, period11, period12, period13, period14, 
                      period15, period16, period17
FROM         CombineSnapshot_detail
WHERE row_type = 'END') p
UNPIVOT
([END] FOR Period IN (period01, period02, period03, period04, period05, period06, period07, period08, period09, period10, period11, period12, period13, period14, 
                      period15, period16, period17)) as unpvt) as mainData) completedData


UPDATE #TempCalc
SET [WK#] = CASE WHEN (wholePeriodsTotal + RemainderGFT) > 0 THEN Round(((([END] - wholePeriodsTotal)/RemainderGFT) + wholePeriods),1) ELSE 0.0 END
FROM #TempCalc


SELECT Style_Pkey, 'WK#' as row_type, [period01], [period02], [period03], [period04], [period05], [period06], [period07], [period08], [period09], [period10], [period11], [period12], [period13], [period14], 
                      [period15], [period16], [period17]
FROM
(SELECT Style_Pkey, period, [WK#] 
    FROM #TempCalc) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX([WK#])
FOR period IN ([period01], [period02], [period03], [period04], [period05], [period06], [period07], [period08], [period09], [period10], [period11], [period12], [period13], [period14], 
                      [period15], [period16], [period17])
) AS PivotTable;
```